# Where do I find the SmartGit trash?

Tags: smartgit, recycle-bin

When deleting untracked files in SmartGit (on Windows) you have to option to actually delete or "Move to trash". Often I use "Move to trash" when I am not 100% sure about deleting something.
I just did "move stuff to trash" which I now need back, but where the **** do I find that trash?

Even a Google search on "SmartGit trash" or "SmartGit recycle bin" does not bring me anywhere.

I looked in the Windows Trashbin, I searched in the AppData dirs... not a clue.

Does anyone have a clue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some debugging and with a little help from SmartGit's support I found out that the problem is a Windows-problem (not a SmartGit problem) and it is by design.

If a Git-repository is on a local disk the Move To Trash functionality works like expected: it moves the file to the Windows trashbin.

If though - as in my case - the repository is on any mounted disk (network or VM) it doesn't work.
Then I found out that if I simply create a file on such a disk, navigate to it in Windows Explorer and delete it from there, Windows asks if I want to delete it permanently (it is never moved to the trashbin).

So case closed.